# Symfony form many-to-many -> many-to-one

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, many-to-one

I have three different entities
- Newsletter
- NewsletterOptions
- Options

I need the NewsletterOptions entity, because I need extra properties in that entity, so a manyToMany relation is no option. Now I'd like to create the following form:

[image]

Therefore I created the following FormTypes:

#### NewsletterType

```
<?php
class NewsletterType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('newsletterOptions', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new NewsletterOptionsType()
        ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Application\Bundle\Entity\Newsletter'
        ));
    }
}
```

#### NewsletterOptionsType

```
class NewsletterOptionsType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('option', 'entity', array(
            'property' => 'name',
            'class' => 'Bundle:Options',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Application\Bundle\Entity\NewsletterOptions'
        ));
    }

}
```

The following entities are specified:

#### Newsletter.orm.yml

```
Application\Bundle\Entity\Newsletter:
    type: entity
    id:
        id:
            type: smallint
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
            options:
              unsigned: true
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
    oneToMany:
        newsletterOptions:
            targetEntity: NewsletterOptions
            mappedBy: newsletter
```

#### NewsletterOptions.orm.yml

```
Application\Bundle\Entity\NewsletterOptions:
    type: entity
    id:
        id:
            type: smallint
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
            options:
                usigned: true
    manyToOne:
        newsletter:
            targetEntity: Newsletter
        option:
            targetEntity: Options
            mappedBy: newsletterOptions
```

#### Options.orm.yml

```
Application\Bundle\Entity\Options:
    type: entity
    id:
        id:
            type: smallint
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
            options:
                usigned: true
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
        regex:
            type: string
            length: 255
    oneToMany:
        newsletterOptions:
            targetEntity: NewsletterOptions
            mappedBy: option
```

When I try to run the script, it results in the following error. Setting the data_class does not help. How can this be solved?

```
The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class Application\Bundle\Entity\NewsletterOptions. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to "Application\Bundle\Entity\NewsletterOptions" or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class Application\Bundle\Entity\NewsletterOptions to scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess.
```

Comment: [Many-to-many association example in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/toza/many-to-many-association-example-in-symfony) in full explained here. It is one-to-many -> middle table <- one-to-many not many-to-many.

Comment: I use the same setup as in the example, the one-to-many relations are the same. The issue is how to render the form.

Comment: Are `FormTypes` header and `Twig templates` header sections not helpful? I guess they would give an idea at least.

Comment: No, I can't get it through. The example code creates a form for the association table. So in my case it will just create a form where I can select a newsletter and an option. Not the form as I'd like.

Comment: You might need `entity` type then. Check `LeagueType.php` here and see `__construct`. http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/djrc/full-webform-style-crud-example-with-an-embedded-associated-entity-in-symfony

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
    $builder->add('option', 'entity', array(
```

(Notice, `option` not `options` since this is how your field is called)